# Can I have a 28cm pot in hand luggage?

Tags: luggage, airports, airport-security, hand-luggage, greece

I couldn't find something via my internet search. Is it allowed through security?

Flying from Athens to a Greek island.

Example of my pot:

[image]

Comment: Which airline are you flying with?

Comment: I don't think that this matter @JoErNanO, what I am afraid is that I will be able to pass the hand-luggage through security (before reaching the gate)!

Comment: Why not? It's an item like any other

Comment: I do not know @JonathanReez..So you are saying that it should be OK!

Comment: @gsamaras Maybe the airline regulation can help shed some light on this.

Comment: @JoErNanOI am flying with Ryanair, but I think they will be OK. The security is my fear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason under the current provided restrictions why it won't be allowed. I have hitherto carried cooked rice in a similar pot through security.

Using TSA as probably the most restrictive agency, this is what information they provide with the disclaimer below:

https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring

> The final decision rests with the TSA officer on whether an item is
>   allowed through the checkpoint

.